# Are short Halachic answers permitted before Birchos Hatorah?

Tags: halacha, birchos-hatorah

If someone is asked a yes-or-no question of Halacha before he said Birchos Hatorah, May he answer?

If Someone is asked what bracha is made on a certain food, (or any similar short-answer question) may he answer before saying Birchos Hatorah?

If one is asked, "what Sefira will we count tonight?" or "Which Parsha do we read this Shabbos?" Is this a halachic question? Does it require Birchos Hatorah before responding?

Is one required to say Birchos Hatorah before asking a Halacha question?

Comment: Yes. OC 47:4. Will post more after saying Birchos Hatorah

Comment: @DoubleAA Is that YES times 4 or just 1 yes? If only one, to which question?? The 1st 2 questions asked "may he answer?, the 3rd and 4th asked whether Birchos Hatorah is required. Can they all be YES?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your first three questions, I'll bring the halacha that @Double AA is referring to in a comment:

[Shulchan Aruch OC 47:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.47.4?lang=bi)

> המהרהר בדברי תורה א"צ לברך: **הגה וה"ה דיכול לפסוק דין בלא נתינת טעם לדבריו** [ר"ן פ"ק דשבת ופרק כל הצלמים כתב דהוי כהרהור]:
>
> One who considers words of Torah does not need to bless. (Gloss: **and this is the law of one who can rule on the law without giving a reason for one's words** [Ran: Chapter 1 of Shabbat and Chapter "All images" - he wrote that it is like considering])

Therefore, yes-or-no questions are allowed. Answering what bracha should be said on a food, is allowed as long as you don't go into explanations, and telling someone what sefira or parsha it is, is also allowed.